# switch for all cases

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I want to check if any strings that was entered belongs to the class Noun.

```
var answer = prompt("enter sentence").toLowerCase();

function Noun(name) {
    this.name = name;
}

spoon = new object("noun");
```

Can i find match between any substring like wwwspoonwww and belonging to any class?

```
 var analysis = function(string) {
    switch (true) {
        case /any string/.test(string):
        if (?){
            console.log("noun");
        }
        else {
            console.log("not noun")
        };
        break;
    }
 };
 analysis(answer);
```

Comment: There's no built-in mechanism to record all members of a class. If you want to do that, you'll need to implement it in your class definition.

Comment: You want to find if there was a noun class instanciated with that string?

Comment: @pi1yau1u I posted an answer which is more aligned with what you asked I think.

Comment: @plalx yeah, i see. I need to be little a little bit speechless for a while - so much help. Thank you!

Comment: @pi1yau1u Welcome to SO ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You want to find if there was a noun class instanciated with that
>   string? - @plalx
>
> Yes i do - @pi1yau1u

In that case you could use a map to store all newly created instances and implement an API that allows you to retrieve them by *name* or retrieve the whole list. I also implemented a `findIn` instance method that will return you the index of that noun in a specified string, or -1 if not found.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ajfPF/1/)

```
var Noun = (function (map) {

    function Noun(name) {
        name = name.toLowerCase();

        var instance = map[name];

        //if there's already a Noun instanciated with that name, we return it
        if (instance) return instance;

        this.name = name;

        //store the newly created noun instance
        map[name] = this;
    }

    Noun.prototype.findIn = function (s) {
        return s.indexOf(this.name);
    };

    Noun.getByName = function (name) {
        return map[name.toLowerCase()];
    };

    Noun.list = function () {
        var m = map, //faster access
            list = [], 
            k;

        for (k in m) list.push(m[k]);

        return list;
    };

    return Noun;

})({});

new Noun('table');
new Noun('apple');

//retrieve a noun by name
console.log('retrieved by name :', Noun.getByName('table'));

//check if a string contains some noun (without word boundaries)
var s = 'I eat an apple on the couch.';

Noun.list().forEach(function (noun) {
    if (noun.findIn(s) !== -1) console.log('found in string: ', noun);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To check if a certain string is within another string you can use `str.indexOf(string);`

You do not need to use the `switch` in this case. But "for all cases" you would use `default:`

Comment: That doesn't answer the question, well part of it but it's quite incomplete.

Comment: The "question" is "switch for all cases". But you did a good job in your answer. I admit I did not go into the "...belong to any class?" in "Can i find match between any substring like wwwspoonwww and belonging to any class?"